# ALTER TABLE takes forever even for a very little table

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, alter-table

I am working with a DB on Heroku.
I tried to add another column without default.
the table has only 3 rows and 5 columns, but the statement still takes forever to finish.

I'm very new to SQL stuff. Is there anything I could do to fix it? A quicker option will be welcome too.

Comment: @meagar The question is quite clear and complete to me, it even specifies that no `DEFAULT` value is used.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a new column requires a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table.

The reason why it takes so long for you is that there is another long running transaction that is holding a lock on the table. Any other lock conflicts with `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`, so your `ALTER TABLE` is blocked.

Terminate the other transaction, and the statement will be done with lightning speed.

Comment: @user9191983  

To ensure there's no other transaction, you can halt you app using [heroku maintenance mode](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode)